# Merge and push to 2 different repos by default

Tags: git, dvcs

Let's say my `.git/config` looks like this:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@github.com:asymmetric/app.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
[remote "upstream"]
    url = git@github.com:dhh/app.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Now, when I'm on the `master` branch, both `git pull` and `git push` will work with the `origin` repo.

Is there a way to have git **pull** from `upstream`, but **push** to `origin`, all without having to specify repos/branches on the command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a single remote that has a different push url from its fetch url. If you run

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:dhh/app.git
git remote set-url --push origin git@github.com:asymmetric/app.git
```

the first command sets the fetch URL for `origin` and the second sets the push URL for `origin`. Since `origin` is used by default this will let you have the behavior you want for `git pull` and `git push`.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible.

If you look at your configuration file:

```
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

you can generalize it to:

```
[branch "x"]
    remote = r
    merge = refs/heads/y
```

This means, if you are on branch `x` and do `git push/pull` (or do `git push/pull x` from "anywhere), it will act on branch `y` of remote `r`.

The closest you can do is an alias.

Comment: Hm, isn't `git push` equivalent to `git push <remote> <merge>` where `remote` and `merge` are configured in `.git/config` for current branch (exactly as asymmetric shows in the question)? The problem is that `push` and `pull` both use these values if they're not specified explicitly. So you can't make `push` and `pull` work with different remotes by default.

Comment: user1111122's solution will create a `pushurl` line in the `[branch "x"]` section